# Font awesome content displayed as text

Tags: php, css, mysql, phpmyadmin, font-awesome

This is my first question right there. I've 2 questions.

*Que 1 -* When inserting an html code from DB, CSS linked in meta does not applied : Why ?

*Que 2 -* In order to solve this, i'm inserting after html code a style tag. But...

I'm currently using MYSQL as DB. Data are inserted into this DB through phpmyadmin, using a SQL script.

When i'm retriving data, the fontawesome content is displayed **as text** instead of an icon. This is how i'm creating an icon element, it's working properly in a simple html doc. But not when the data is inserted via a SQL script.
It's **working too** when i'm updating via the phpMyAdmin's GUI.

> Css section

```
  #sinner .sinner_chart_item::before {
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 4em;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 5;
        line-height: 3em;
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        margin-top: 15px;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }

  #sinner .sinner_chart_item:nth-child(1)::before {
        content: "\f2c8";
    }
```

> Here a part of my SQL code :

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS = @@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE = @@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE = 'TRADITIONAL';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `esano`
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
  COLLATE utf8_bin;
USE `esano`;

[...]

CREATE TABLE course (
  id     INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  topic  INT                    NOT NULL,
  title  VARCHAR(255)           NOT NULL,
  video  VARCHAR(255),
  script TEXT                   NOT NULL,
  interact TEXT                 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8,  ENGINE = InnoDB;

[...]


UPDATE `course`
SET `interact` = '<div class="interact__container" id="sinner">[...]</div>
                  <style>[...]</style>'
WHERE `course`.`id` = 7;
```